# Odoo app installation not showing

Tags: python, odoo

After installing Odoo it shows only empty page apps not able to install please be a guide

[this is the screen for after installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raG6O.png)

Comment: May I know which App you installed ?

Comment: odoo CRM application

Comment: Maybe you can show the browser console errors, it could be a js problem.

Comment: this is my console error -Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
/web/webclient/translations:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall web or base module

```
odoo-bin -u base -d my_database
```

Comment: Thank you guys I reinstall the odoo and resolve this issue.